# scrollTop() !== does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I would like to trigger an event with jQuery when the scroll bar is not at the top of the document. So far I can only get this to work when it's at the top of the document. "!==" does not seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
    alert("top!")
  };
});
```

Comment: The scrolling tends to happen after the page has loaded. Are you looking for the initial scroll position, or do you want to detect any scrolling? How about End, e.g.?

Comment: Was about to mention this too.  You may want to connect this if check to the scroll event.

Comment: You are looking to bind to the jQuery [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event.

Comment: There is no event attached... You haven't told the code to check when the user is scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() { /* or whatever element you want to attach to */
      if($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
        alert("top!")
      };
  });
});
```

Of course, this will trigger every time you scroll to the top, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Or the shorthand ready function `jQuery(function($) {`, which is sometimes necessary when other script libraries are being used...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `.scroll()` event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {
        alert("not top!")
      };
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EX2q2/